Degree 1 projective subvarieties are linear
I want to show that a closed subvariety (closed reduced equidimensional subscheme) $X \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ having degree $1$ is linear over an arbitrary field $k$, possibly non-algebraically closed. I've already shown this when $k = \bar{k}$, and am unsure how to reduce it to this case.
I know that if $X \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ has degree $1$, then so does $X \times_k \bar{k} \subseteq \mathbb{P}_{\bar{k}}^n$, and hence the reduction of $X \times_k \bar{k}$ is linear. How do I then conclude that $X$ is?

Let's name some stuff:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\Bbb P^n_{\overline{k}} @>{v}>> \Bbb P^n\\
@V{g}VV @VV{f}V \\
\operatorname{Spec} \overline{k} @>{u}>> \operatorname{Spec} k
\end{CD}$$
Since $u$ is flat, we have that $v^*\mathcal{I}_X\cong\mathcal{I}_{X_\overline{k}}$, so $v^*\mathcal{I}_X(1)\cong\mathcal{I}_{X_\overline{k}}(1)$ and therefore we have that $H^0(\Bbb P^n_k,\mathcal{I}_X(1))\otimes_k \overline{k} = H^0(\Bbb P^n_{\overline{k}},\mathcal{I}_{X_{\overline{k}}}(1))$, so $X$ is contained in a linear space of dimension $\dim X_{\overline{k}}$. But $X_\overline{k}$ has the same dimension as $X$, and the only closed subscheme of dimension $d$ in $\Bbb P^d_k$ is $\Bbb P^d_k$.
